# SystemStackError in Rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment, asset-pipeline

When `config.assets.compile = true` is set in production environment (Rails 3.2) then the `SystemStackError` is raised.

The workaround is to set it to `false` (which is ugly really).

This doesn't happen in a brand new app.

Additionally running the `RAILS_ENV=staging rails s` still throws the `SystemStackError` while the `staging.rb` is empty or same as production or even doesn't exist.

More details in the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4773#issuecomment-3752195).

Any thought how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Authlogic [issue](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/260).

I just decided to switch over to Devise.

Answer (score -3):

copy the content in config/environments/production.rb into config/environments/staging.rb

Comment: Did you read the issue I provided there? Same happens when the content is the same.